# Queries with word+space is not working as expected in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Well to begin with I am new to elasticsearch and may not have used all the possible ways

I am having documents like 'car hire','car hired','car hire for airport', 'hire car toyota', 'ca','ca test','ca test1','ca test2','test3 ca','test4 ca' etc.
Whenever I am running a query like,

['query' => ['term' => ['fld_name' => 'ca']]]
I am getting CA in return.

But, whenever I am trying to execute queries with (word+space) like:

['query' => ['term' => ['fld_name' => 'ca ']]] //This wont return any value as it matches of exact values
['query' => ['match' => ['fld_name' => 'ca ']]] //This returns values like 'car hire' and 'hire car toyota' as well..

Here I was expecting it to return ca test,ca test1,ca test2,'test3 ca','test4 ca'..

I have tried almost all the types of queries like query_string,match,match_phrase,match_phrase_prefix but have not got it to work..

My problem is not limited to single word searches, it can contain [two words+space] like,

['query' => ['match' => ['fld_name' => 'car hire ']]] //This should not return 'car hired'

Please help..!!

**Here is the sample settings and mapping**

```
"settings": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "analysis": {
          "char_filter": {
            "punctuation": {
              "pattern": "[\\.,]",
              "type": "pattern_replace"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "search_partial": {
              "filter": [
                "word_delimiter",
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "unique"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "punctuation"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "search_all": {
              "filter": [
                "word_delimiter",
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "unique"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "punctuation"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
          },
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0"
   }



"mappings": {
        "index_type": {
            "_all":       { "enabled": false  },
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "integer" },
                "fld_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "partial_front": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "partial_name_index",
                            "search_analyzer": "search_partial"
                        },
                        "exact": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "raw_data_index"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "full_name_index",
                    "search_analyzer": "search_all"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: adding your schema mappings can be helpful for us

Comment: could you please add the definitions of `/_settings` and `/_mappings` of your index? This sounds like it could be related to these.

Comment: have you tried query string query with  wild card eg: ca* or car hire*

Comment: have you tried query string query with wild card eg: ca* or car hire*

Yes I have tried it.. This is working fine, but with space at the end i.e. car hire *, is not working as expected

Comment: I see `search_partial` in your settings, but not `partial_name_index`. Assuming it works the same way, it shouldn't be a problem. It's just important that those 2 analyzers work well together. You can use the [analyzer api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see how they transform some input text; ie. `ca `.
Does your search for  'ca ' return all values? And as for the last example with 'car hire '. A normal match query usually only has to match 1 term. Otherwise use the `minimum_should_match` parameter.